# How to check the required dependencies for a package?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I want to install the ndiswrapper packages (utils, -dkms and -common) in my Ubuntu 13.04 live-usb. However, since I don't have wi-fi while I'm on the Daily build, I can't install them directly, so I have to return to my default 12.10 installation to download the appropriate packages and dependencies.

The package dependencies are listed here:

> http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ndiswrapper-common
>
> http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ndiswrapper-dkms
>
> http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ndiswrapper-utils-1.9

Though -common and -utils have relatively few dependencies, -dkms has quite a few, and most of these have their own dependencies. I also realize that many of these dependencies are installed by default in 13.04.

So I was wondering if there is some way to quickly determine only the packages I would actually need to download and install to get ndiswrapper working in 13.04. Something like a simulation of an "apt-get install" in 13.04 that would output all the missing packages for a default installation. Thanks!

Comment: Per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) 13.04 is off-topic here due to being in beta.  If you can edit this question to refer to 12.10 please do.  Otherwise this will probably be closed as off-topic.  Thanks!

Comment: It's really a general question that applies to any version. Like an upgrade to a stable release, for example.

Comment: @RobieBasak Okay, then it's fine.  I was't quite sure about it myself.

Comment: I would recommend simulating the install, like:  sudo apt-get -s install ndiswrapper-common, this would he show you what packages would actually install. Have not tried it yet but I am pretty sure there is a way to simulate  the install process.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install the `devscripts` package.
2. Run `chdist create raring`
3. Edit `~/.chdist/etc/apt/sources.list` and enter your sources as they would be for raring (eg. `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main universe restricted multiverse`)
4. Run `chdist apt-get raring update`
5. Run `chdist apt-get raring --print-uris install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-dkms ndiswrapper-utils-1.9`

This will give you a list of URIs to download, which you can transfer and then use `dpkg -i` on directly.

Comment: I followed your instructions but got an inordinate amount (30+) of "NEW packages that will be installed", including "keyboard-configuration" and "e2fsprogs", which leads me to believe chdist is not exclusively considering the ndiswrapper packages. Am I doing something wrong, or is this proper functionality? If so, how can I focus in only on those packages? P.S. when I do "ndiswrapper-common" only the package itself is outputted (since it has no dependencies), so I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: It's pulling in all required dependencies (and I think all recommendations by default). On a real system many of them would already be installed, so you wouldn't see as many.

Comment: So is there a way to filter out the packages that are already installed by default in 13.04? Maybe by taking the list chdist gives me and matching it against a list of all the packages in 13.04?